# NserviceBus saga calling out web services

Tags: architecture, nservicebus, saga

In NServiceBus [documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/#accessing-databases-and-other-resources-from-a-saga) there is statement that sagas should not call out to web services:

> Other than interacting with its own internal state, a saga should not access a database, call out to web services, or access other resources - neither directly nor indirectly by having such dependencies injected into it.

Since there is no explanation on why not to do that I would like to ask community to help me with this one.

I understand why I cannot query database: state might have changed between issuing event and its processing. The part which I don't understand is about web services.

Why is it bad practice to POST to let's say Shipping web service with command to ShipOrder with given ID?

Comment: Good call! Apparently, our documentation is lacking. I'll try to update it soon.

Comment: I created an issue for now : https://github.com/Particular/docs.particular.net/issues/3704
If you happen to feel like submitting a PR, that would be great. Otherwise someone from the team will do it eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually better to raise this kind of questions with the Particular Software team itself on https://discuss.particular.net/ or via regular support. The reason is that these questions are rather open and tend to create a thread of replies.

Since I am working for Particular Software, let's continue it here. You can always copy the question/thread.

The main reason is possible contention and consistency of saga state. Depending on persister, saga state is retrieved and persisted with either pessimistic or optimistic locking. Either way, if the transaction takes too long, it's possible another message will come in that correlates to the same saga instance. It might be processed on a different (concurrent) thread (or perhaps a scaled out endpoint) and it will either immediately fail (pessimistic locking) or while trying to persist the state (optimistic locking). The message will be retried.

This is normal behavior and not something that can be avoided. However the longer the lock is open, the more likely it is going to happen. The usual advice is to NEVER do anything else besides orchestration of a business process. So not even retrieving or storing your own business data. But with webservices you have no control over the webservice and it might take a connection timeout or ever longer before the message fails. Correlated messages will fail even faster and it's likely they'll eventually end up in the error queue.

Something that can be avoided by not doing anything else but orchestrate the business process and 'just' send messages. Keeping locks on data as short as possible.

Comment: So I guess its very dependant on Saga construction itself. In my case Saga will just manage set of services like
- call service1
- when service1 finishes work call service2
- when service2 finishes work complete
I guess I should be safe in this case?

Comment: If it could be done sequentially, I would create two handlers that call these services. Then from my saga fire messages to those handlers. The saga would be to check if everything completes. So both handlers need to reply back to the saga stating that everything went okay. Saga can set a timeout for 24h or so. If timeout comes in, we can verify if work has been done. If not, we raise an alert somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the functional answer from Dennis, I also feel there are aspects of code health / code architecture here, particularly separation of concerns. The saga's function is orcehstration - modelling a long-running business process. I would suggest that the cost of having the saga invoke a method that in turn makes the webservice call is very low, and the increase in code health is large relative to the cost.

To put it a different way, I would suggest that the orchestration is business logic, where as making the call out to a webservice is more like infrastructure code than business logic.

There are many reasons that this distinction is important, but one that comes instantly to mind is your test strategy. You may very well have a different test strategy for infrastructure code than your test strategy for business logic. That's difficult to do when a class has a mix of both.

Comment: I agree with you about separating concerns. My saga is just calling some service through interface (which under the hood calls web service) so the only code in saga itself is related to orchestration. But the given documentation says that I shouldn't call web services from saga even indirectly.